# AuthenticationFailed message when using MERGE with Azure Storage Table API

Tags: php, azure, azure-table-storage

I'm getting an `AuthenticationFailed` message when attempting to use the `MERGE` verb for an API call into Azure Storage API (specifically Tables).

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/insert-or-merge-entity) indicates that the signature hashing and body content should be the same for both `POST` and `MERGE` calls which it is - I'm using the same function for GET, POST and MERGE and only the MERGE is getting a failed authentication.

Below is a couple of lines to indicate how I'm generating the signature for each call:

```
  $method = 'MERGE';
  $currentDate = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s T");
  $contentType = 'application/json;odata=nometadata';

  $target = array(
    "href" => "https://[STORAGE_ACCOUNT].table.core.windows.net/[STORAGE_TABLE](PartitionKey='[PARTITION_KEY]',RowKey='1')",
    "canonical" => "/[STORAGE_ACCOUNT]/[STORAGE_TABLE]()"
  );

  // Generate the array of data we need to create a signature to authorise these calls
  $signatureArray = array(
    $method,               /*HTTP Verb*/
    '',                    /*Content-MD5*/
    $contentType,          /*Content-Type*/
    $currentDate,          /*Date*/
    $target['canonical']   /*CanonicalizedResource*/
  );

  // Build the signature by hashing the signatureArray with the Azure Storage Account secret key
  $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', urldecode(utf8_encode(implode("\n", $signatureArray))), base64_decode(variable_get('az_storage_key', '')), true));
```

The MD5 hash of the content seems to have no effect, regardless of how I do it and it doesn't seem to be required for POST calls which go through fine without that being included.

I'm hoping someone has come across this before and can help me understand why the authentication would fail for `MERGE` and not `POST` or `GET`.

I should note that for a couple of reasons, I'm not able to use the Azure PHP SDK.

Comment: Please try by adding `(PartitionKey='[PARTITION_KEY]',RowKey='1')` to your canonical resource string. It should be something like `"/[STORAGE_ACCOUNT]/[STORAGE_TABLE](PartitionKey='[PARTITION_KEY]',RowKey='1')"`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in this case was to ensure that the canonical URL included the parameters passed in the target href for MERGE calls. Changing:

```
$target = array(
  "href" => "https://[STORAGE_ACCOUNT].table.core.windows.net/[STORAGE_TABLE](PartitionKey='[PARTITION_KEY]',RowKey='1')",
  "canonical" => "/[STORAGE_ACCOUNT]/[STORAGE_TABLE]()"
);
```

to this instead:

```
$target = array(
  "href" => "https://[STORAGE_ACCOUNT].table.core.windows.net/[STORAGE_TABLE](PartitionKey='[PARTITION_KEY]',RowKey='1')",
  "canonical" => "/[STORAGE_ACCOUNT]/[STORAGE_TABLE](PartitionKey='[PARTITION_KEY]',RowKey='1')"
);
```

The reason this wasn't failing on `GET` or `POST` calls was because both of those were targeted at `()` (I was using $filter for GETs) so the canonical URL was fine for those calls.

Thank you to @guarav-mantri who solved this in the comments.